# Little problems with using Jquery array?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I trying to make pricing page, when every user can choose price of tarif whatever he want. But i have a problem when i start new Array.I clik on checkbox with tarif and this label write me Undefined. I cant still figure it out.

There is a jquery code.
With this i trying to initialize array.

```
<?php 
   $this->registerJs("

       var tarif = [];

")
?>
<?php foreach ($tarif2 as $tf2){
   $this->registerJs("
       tarif[".$tf2->tarif_id."] = [];
       tarif[".$tf2->tarif_id."][".$tf2->tarif_lenght."]=[];
       tarif[".$tf2->tarif_id."][".$tf2->tarif_lenght."][".$tf2->tarif_user_count."]=". $tf2->tarif_price.";


 ");} ?>
```

And on end of the page i have this jquery code, which is used as output for total price.

```
<?php  $this->registerJs("

     $('.order_action').change(function(){

      var user_count = $('#order_users').val();
      var tarif_lenght  = $('#order_period').val();
      var tarif_currency  = $('#order_currency').val();


      $('.order_checkbox').each(function( i, val ) {

      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
       tarif[parseInt($(this).data('id'))][parseInt(tarif_lenght)][parseInt(user_count)];
       console.log(tarif[$(this).data('id')][tarif_lenght][user_count]);

       var advanced_price = tarif[[$(this).data('.order_checkbox')]+[tarif_lenght]*[user_count]];
       var total = advanced_price +' '+ [tarif_currency];




      }

      $('#order_total_price').html(total);

      });
});
")

?>
```

If i click on any checkbox with price, it write me Undefined + Currency.
I still dont know where is a problem.
I using framework Yii2.

Thanks all for the help :).

Comment: Are you trying to use php to echo a JS array? Why don't you use php to generate a php array, json_encode it and use it in the js code? It's the right approach and will solve you many of the problems you are facing

Comment: I trying to make it through the jquery. I use parseInt for solve my problem, but this didnt work too. In console log the price of tarif is, but problem is somewhere else. I didnt know where.

Comment: I figure it out! Make it as you tell me and it works perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome. Post your solution for further reference by others!